# Error in Visual Studio while debugging "parameter 'basepath' cannot have zero length"

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I am facing this error while trying to debug C code in Visual Studio 2010. When searched in google all i could find something related is as below

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/615793/badly-formed-debugger-command-causes-error-parameter-basepath-cannot-have-zero-length.

Any suggestions to overcome this is really appreciated . Thanks

Comment: I fixed the problem by giving up.

Answer (score 12):

Same problem, I was building a function library to load on demand, but got this message.  It is a matter of don't quote the VSDebugger options.

Remove the double quotes from 
  the full path of the executable
  the command arguments
  the working directory

embedded spaces can be passed to the command line by single quotes, if really required.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error message with only the name of the executable in the command (so no full path). It used to work pefectly, but suddenly it didn't. I checked the path variable and somehow there were two consecutive ';' in there. I fixed that and the problem disappeared.

Comment: Also Visual Studio must be restarted after fixing the %PATH%.

Comment: Also make sure there are no quoted entries in %PATH%, if there are, just remove the quotation marks (they are not required, even for paths with spaces).

Comment: Excellent find. Just fixed attaching to running executable without having to supply path. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In my case the command line did not have .exe extension at the end (Properties->ConfigurationProperties->Debugging->Command). Adding  the extension fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For me "Parameter "basePath" cannot have zero length" was caused when I set my configuration properties->debugging->command to "regsvr32.exe $(TargetPath)" to debug my project registration.  I fixed this by setting the command to "regsvr32.exe" and command arguments to "$(TargetPath)"

Answer (score 0):

If you set up a makefile project (I guess it's the case), be sure that the file you put in Configuration Properties -> Debugging -> Command exists.

(and I think it doesn't accept batch files, but I'm not 100% sure)

Comment: I had to dump my VM and get a new one to get this error fixed. I am not too sure on your soln though. I would want to thank you for pulling something which is really old like this and having patience to answer it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

check your path in: Configuration Properties -> Debugging -> Working Directory.
check that this path is a valid path in your machine.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem with setting value of Properties->Debugging->Command to another, and after it set back to my default.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure Visual Studio is running "As Administrator". This fix it for me.