"Parameter "basepath" cannot be a relative path" error in Visual Studio
I am unable to debug VS because of the parameter basepath cannot be a relative path error. This is version 2017.
The build is successful, but since I am completely new to this IDE, I am unable to understand what the problem is.

I tried to check the %PATH% following another thread recommendation but I am totally clueless where to find that and what should I do with it


Please edit your question and add your programming language Tags to increase your post visibility

I did now, thank you.

I checked a similar case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9497494/error-in-visual-studio-while-debugging-parameter-basepath-cannot-have-zero-leand found that the relevant settings may be in "command". I'll give you a screenshot of my settings, and you can check it against them.

